# How can I use IsNewResource in DiffSuppressFunc?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: I'm developing a TF Provider.

I'm adding  the [CustomizeDiff](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/customizing-differences) function instead however there's a gotcha: if a resource attribute references another attribute (`foo = bar.resourcefoo.xyz`), it seems to return `""` as value on an initial `terraform plan` run.

Its signature is

```
// See Resource documentation.
type CustomizeDiffFunc func(context.Context, *ResourceDiff, interface{}) error
```

and `ResourceDiff` doesn't have `IsNewResource()` that `ResourceData` has. Are there any workarounds to have something similar to `IsNewResource()`?

In other words, I want something similar to

```
func SetDiff(ctx context.Context, diff *schema.ResourceDiff, meta interface{}) error {
    if diff.IsNewResource() { return nil }
    // Otherwise run the check

    ...
    // If we are increasing "size" then the new value must be
    // a multiple of the old value.
    if new.(int) <= old.(int) {
      return nil
    }
```

Some hacks I discovered:

```
#1: 
if diff.Id() == "" { return nil }

#2:
if diff.HasChange()
```

Comment: This is SDKv2, or plugin framework?

Comment: @Matt: This is SDKv2